# Какую выбрать IDE для программирования под Android на Java?

Tags: android, ide, java

Есть потребность программировать под Android. Выбрал Java. Какие IDE популярные на даный момент? Какие у них преимущества и недостатки? Сам рассматриваю IDEA Community edition, NetBeans, Eclipse.

Comment: А что вам не нравится в `<IDE_name_1>` по сравнению с `<IDE_name_2>`?

Comment: Это уже вкусовщина. Мне, например, в eclipse нравится наличие EPIC (помимо андровозможностей), но другим-то оно зачем? Так что выбирайте что лично вам больше нравится, не понравится - смените, делов-то.

Comment: Есть немало инструментов препост-оптимизации производительности из за багов в самих IDE, защиты, рефакторинга и т. д. и т.п..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Изначально я пользовался Eclipse, но когда JetBrains выпустили Community версию Intelij IDEA, сразу перешел на нее. 
Там много плюшек, по сравнению с эклипсом:
Юзер-френдли интерфейс, очень удобный рефакторинг, автодополнение кода, для андроид очень удобный редактор форм, гораздо лучше чем у эклипса(хотя я им и не пользуюсь, пишу ручками все), даже взять Debug режим, для новичка он в IDEA гораздо понятней и удобней, да и много других мелочей, которые радуют.

Все вещи, которые есть в IDEA можно добить плагинами в эклипсе, но зачем это, если есть все сразу в одном месте.

Да и к тому же, Jet Brains умеют делать хорошие продукты.

Comment: Так же можете прочитать небольшой абзац (раздел "маленькое лирическое отступление") в этой статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/178283. Человек описывает, почему он выбрал IDEA и отказался от Eclipse.

Comment: Я тоже сторонник IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Отдаю предпочтение Eclipse. Сейчас, тем более, Установить все, что нужно для разработки под Android - это только скачать Eclipse с http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
Eclipse и SDK в одном флаконе

Comment: Я тоже писал в Eclipse и отдаю ему предпочтение, т.к. всё в нём удобно и понятно, установил плагин и радуйся кодингу!:-)

Comment: +1 в сторону Эклипса. Так уж сложилось, что пишу в нем с самого начала своей джава-практики, пробовал на айдею и нетБинс пересесть - не подружился с ними.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, *Android Studio* вполне устраивает. Правда если слабый ноутбук, то эмулятор будет запускаться вечно.

По мне удобнее и комфортнее в Студии, но *Intellij Idea* быстрее, легче и не виснет. Да и на слабых ноутбуках спокойно под *Android* с ней пишут. А вот со Studio придется возиться, если слабый ноутбук/компютер.

Answer (score -2):

Эклипс и только эклипс! Прямая работа с гугл. Все остальное от лукавого!

Comment: Не надо так однозначно - не забываем про личное мнение и плюрализм мнений :)

Comment: Это как называть негра из мали афроамериканцем из чувства толерантности?)

Comment: Нет, это ласковое обучение правилам поведения в Хэшкод