# Отличия сред разработки под android.

Tags: eclipse, java, android-studio, android

Всем доброго времени суток!

Пишу под андроид на Java в Eclipse+ADT. Какие ещё среды разработки стоит использовать и почему? Видел обзор на Android Studio - вроде всё круто, но стоит ли переходить на неё? Или есть что-то ещё?

P.S. В частности в упомянутом обзоре порадовала заявленная фича соединения линиями блоков кода. В Eclipse этого не хватает.

Comment: Рекомендую почитать - http://startandroid.ru/ru/articles/listofarticles/284-znakomstvo-s-android-studio.html Лично я сижу на IDEA, до студии еще не дозрел. Но вот эклипс выбросил давно уже.

Comment: Меня в свое время тоже впечатлил обзор Android Studio, но на ней не напишешь ничего кроме Android приложений, и я установил IDEA, то же самое в общем. Eclipse банально баговый, одно меня просто убивало, в XML редакторе строки пляшут, пишешь в одну строку, а она поплыла, переустановки не помогали!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я уже отвечал по поводу [Eclipse vs IDEA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216832/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java).

Сейчас для разработки под андроид использую Android Studio ибо она заточена сильней под это дело. Есть много готовых шаблонов(Navigation Drawer,LoginActivity,Master/Detail Flow  и etc). 
Да, она позволяет работать с проектами только для андроид. Но мне это не мешало поставить рядом IDEA, не так уж она места много занимает.

Единственный минус(после перехода, не считаю таковым) это то, что она постоянно предлагает перевести проект на Gradle.

Я пользовался AS с самого начала, как только ее представили. С тех пор она стала гораздо стабильней. Я считаю ее лучшей IDE для разработки под андроид.

Comment: @Andreich
Cпасибо за подробный ответ!