# Intellij Idea vs Android Studio

Tags: android, java

Вопрос такой:
Собрался писать под android. Есть 3 IDE:Eclipse, Android Studio, Intellij IDEA 13.

Почти все книги используют Eclipse в качестве среды. Intellij IDEA взята за основу Android Studio, но вроде как сыровата. Хочется писать в Intellij IDEA 13. Какие можете дать советы и есть ли книги где в качестве среды используют Intellij IDEA? Пробовал писать на Eclipse простые вещи под android.

Comment: все проблемы гуглятся за пару минут... так что idea....

Comment: Я перешел на Intellij и не жалею, все быстро и функционально. Кроме работы с gradle при медленном инете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[да было уже не раз.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320709/java-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android)